# logback RollingFileAppender not rolling files

Tags: java, logging, logback, rollingfileappender

I have a logback config having a RollingFileAppender appender with SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy. However, it seems whenever my application runs logback doesn't roll files and keeps appending to the same file over and over again.

My application executes for a little time not more than a few seconds. I thought that would be the issue so I even used cleanHistoryOnStart option but even that is not working. Please help me.

Here's the config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="20 seconds">
  <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] :: %-5p :: %-10class{0}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="processLogFileAppender"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <file>/home/elkapp/ETL_Logs/ETLLogsGenerator/logs/ETLLogsGenerator.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>/home/elkapp/ETL_Logs/ETLLogsGenerator/logs/ETLLogsGenerator-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                <totalSizeCap>500MB</totalSizeCap>
                <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
                <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] :: %-5p :: %-10class{0}:%L - %m%n            </pattern>
        </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.ibm.etllogsgenerator" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="processLogFileAppender"/>
    <!--appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/-->
  </logger>

</configuration>
```

Comment: What version of logback are you using?  Some releases had issues with SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy

Answer (score 0):

Change the policy to

```
class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"
```

you can see an example [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/253/logback-xml-limit-the-size-of-files)